# how to pivot on a column on json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, pivot

I have data in json format and I would like to pivot on the nym dimension.
the json data are in the following format:

```
data=[{
    l: 'es',
    maxversion: '20210620',
    nym: 'http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary#antonym',
    count: '2827',
  },
  {
    l: 'es',
    maxversion: '20210620',
    nym: 'http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary#approximateSynonym',
    count: '0',
  },
  {
    l: 'es',
    maxversion: '20210620',
    nym: 'http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary#holonym',
    count: '0',
  },
{
    l: 'es',
    maxversion: '20210620',
    nym: 'http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary#hypernym',
    count: '1589',
  },
  .
  .
  .

  },]
```

I would like to have this format after pivot, to be able to use them in a graphic library:

```
[{
    l: 'es',
    maxversion: '20210620',
    antonym:'2827' ,
    approximateSynonym: '0',
    holonym:'0',
    hypernym:'1589', 
    hyponym:913,
    meronym:'0',
    synonym:'25821',
    troponym: '0'
  },
 ]
```

Comment: Hi Amnay, SO aren't a coding workforce. We're here for help, but, can you try it and post some of your tests?

Comment: hi Sakura, I have just published my results in response

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) if the other properties (`l`, `maxversion`) are the same for every entry.

```js
function pivot(data){
  return data.reduce((accumulator, {nym, count, ...rest}) => ({
    ...accumulator,
    ...rest,
    [nym.split('#')[1]]: count
  }), {});
}
```

Otherwise you have to group them first by some key.

```js
function groupBy(data, keyname){
    let result = {};
    data.forEach((item) => {
        const key = item[keyname];
        result[key] = [...(result[key] || []), item];
    })
    return Object.values(result);
}
```

**Example usage grouped by `l`:**

```js
const result = groupBy(data, 'l').map(pivot);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my data is not the same I used the groupBy function `const result = groupBy(data, 'l').map(pivot);` and it works perfectly for me here is what I get:

```
[
  {
    l: 'es',
    maxversion: '20210620',
    antonym: '2827',
    approximateSynonym: '0',
    holonym: '0',
    hypernym: '1589',
    hyponym: '913',
    meronym: '0',
    synonym: '25821',
    troponym: '0'
  },
  {
    l: 'bg',
    maxversion: '20210620',
    antonym: '40',
    approximateSynonym: '0',
    holonym: '0',
    hypernym: '0',
    hyponym: '0',
    meronym: '0',
    synonym: '17399',
    troponym: '0'
  },
```